# How to refresh the data from a "live" connection in Tableau in development mode

Tags: tableau-api

When a `Data Source` was created as "live" the data available in it was pulled into the Workbook.   How can the data be refreshed?

[image]

I am using `Tableau Desktop Professional 10.5.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: need to edit the `Connection`  Then choose `Data`|`Refresh Data Source`

[image]